# How can I vertically center text within flexbox when each line-height is different?

Tags: css, flexbox, line-height

I have three text section horizontally and each text has different `line-height`. But, they should be vertically aligned.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

p:first-child {
  line-height: 1.33;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  line-height: 1.65;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>texttext1</p>
  <p>texttext2</p>
  <p>texttext3</p>
</div>
```

However, when I use `align-items` of flex, it doesn't work. Is there other solutions?

Comment: They seem to be aligning vertically already? Even if you set one of the line heights to an extreme value, they still align the same don't they?

Comment: @Acidic9 Did you run my code? It isn't vertically aligned (middle) I edited

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a baseline alignment

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

p:first-child {
  line-height: 1.33;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  line-height: 1.65;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>texttext1</p>
  <p>texttext2</p>
  <p>texttext3</p>
</div>
```